# How to connect avd wear emulator with my phone using the wear OS app?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-virtual-device

I need to connect the avd wear emulator with my smartphone. When I searched the documentation for this [here](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/get-started/creating#pair-phone-with-avd), it said to go to settings then device setting then tap emulator.

I don't understand which settings and device settings it is talking about. The Wear OS app on my phone keeps showing "waiting for the emulator to connect". I am really stuck at this. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It finally worked. I enabled the developer options in my avd emulator and enabled adb debugging and debugging over bluetooth from the developer options. Then followed the steps and the avd emulator connected with my phone. Thanks @selcukokuyucu for your help but  unfortunately I have android 7.1.1 in my smartphone.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Android Studio pairing assistant.

From document:

> From the device dropdown in Android Studio, click Wear OS emulator
> pairing assistant. Select a phone and a Wear AVD to pair with one
> another. If none are available, click View AVD Manager to set up a
> phone or watch AVD. Then click Next.
>
> Android Studio attempts to launch and set up a bridge between the two
> devices. If you do not have the Wear OS app installed on the phone,
> you will be prompted to download the Companion app from the Play
> Store.
>
> If prompted, open the Companion app once it is downloaded. On the
> phone, in the Wear OS app, begin the standard pairing process. For
> example, on the welcome screen, tap the Set It Up button.
> Alternatively, if an existing watch is already paired, in the upper
> left drop-down, tap Add a New Watch. On the phone, in the Wear OS app,
> tap the Overflow button, and then tap Pair with Emulator.

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/get-started/creating#pairing-assistant

This feature is only available for Android 11+